# Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: 'There is already a lease present.'

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-webjobs, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to create a webjob project in .NET core 3.1. I followed the following [guide]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started , except instead of connecting to a storage account, I connect using "UseDevelopmentStorage=true" for the connection string and have the Storage emulator running.

Every couple of builds I get the exception : "**Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: 'There is already a lease present.'**". The exception is thrown at

```
using (host)
{
    await host.RunAsync();
}
```

This does not happen on every build, and apart from using TimerTrigger, I don't use any other storage functions.

Does anyone know what is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I did solve it, but wanted to test for a couple of days. I also experienced an exception when trying to add a new method to Functions.cs. This led me to believe that something else was going on.

What fixed it for me was to remove the storage emulator and downloaded a fresh version, since then I no longer get the exceptions and I can add new functions.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what trigger you use, when you run webjob, you need to write your running log into blob storage. Here you use local storage with `UseDevelopmentStorage=true`.

The [Lease Blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/lease-blob) operation creates and manages a lock on a blob for write and delete operations. The lock duration can be 15 to 60 seconds, or can be infinite. In versions prior to 2012-02-12, the lock duration is 60 seconds.

There is the possibility cause the issue "There is already a lease present" due to concurrent blob storage usage.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand that the error is caused by concurrent blob usage, what I don't understand is what else is using it? Do you mean that the lease persist between builds?

Comment: Yes, the blob may lease so if you create a build before the blob available, you will get the error message.